# How to draw Canvas in WebView?

Tags: javascript, android, canvas, webview, android-webview

I'm making an app where people will be able to place circles in WebView. So, my 
algorithm is:

1. Detect long click
2. Get finger coordinates on WebView
3. Draw circle in Canvas

So at first I was able to write a code that would draw a circle on `LongClick`, the only problem was that when I changed scale(zoomed), circle moved from it's place. With the help of karaokyo answer I have fixed this moving issue) with adding `scale` float `Canvas.drawCircle(x * scale, y * scale, 10, p)`, where `scale = getScale()`. 
Unfortunately new problem appeared - when I make the circle it draws in wrong coordinates. This image shows what I mean:
[image]

```
public DrawWebView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super (context, attrs);
    wv1 = (DrawWebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    wv1.loadUrl("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Pictures/ScolDetectPics/boxes.jpg");
    wv1.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    wv1.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    wv1.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    wv1.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    wv1.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true); 
    wv1.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
    mContext = context;





public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    int action = event.getAction(); 


    switch (action) { 
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        draw = true;
        this.invalidate();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:   
        this.invalidate();
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
        this.invalidate();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:

        break; 

    default: 
        break; 
    }
    return true;
}


@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
{

    super.onDraw (canvas);
    text = MainActivity.text;

    zoomPos = MainActivity.zoomPos;
    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setColor (Color.RED);

    if(initScale == 0){
        initScale = getScale();
    }

    float scale = getScale();

    float refScale = scale/initScale;

    if(MainActivity.drawConfirm){
    zoomPos = MainActivity.zoomPos;
    draw1 = true;
    }
    canvas.drawCircle(330 * refScale, 618 * refScale, 10, p);
    //text.setText(Float.toString(scale));
    text.setText(Float.toString(initScale));
    canvas.drawCircle(330, 618, 10, p);
    if(draw1){
    canvas.drawCircle(zoomPos.x * refScale, zoomPos.y * refScale, 10, p);
    }

}
```

}

Also if I double-tap multiple times circles(both) appear in wrong place, move to the right place when I click.

[image]

If you know how to do this or know a good tutorial - it would be much appreciated.

[Update for karaokyo's answer]

I've copied your code, but circle's still in the wrong place, in fact, `initialScale` value is 2.0. It is clearly seen on this image.
1. Circle that has moving issue, but in correct coordinates.
2. Circle without moving issue, coordinates multiplied by `scale = getScale`.
3. Circle without moving issue, coordinates multiplied by `scale/initScale`

[image]

Comment: I think you're better off drawing the circles using javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address your circle moving problem, you would have to adjust your coordinates based on the zoom scale of the WebView. For the long press, set up a `GestureDetector` that saves the click location and current scale `onLongPress` to be used in your `onDraw`:

```
public class DrawWebView extends WebView {
    private GestureDetector mDetector;
    private float mInitialScale;
    private int mX;
    private int mY;

    public DrawWebView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public DrawWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public DrawWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    public void init(){
        loadUrl("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Pictures/boxes.jpg");
        setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);

        mDetector = new GestureDetector(getContext(), new GestureDetector.OnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                mX = (int) e.getX() + getScrollX();
                mY = (int) e.getY() + getScrollY();
                mInitialScale = getScale();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
                return false;
            }
        });

        setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw (canvas);

        float scale = getScale() / mInitialScale;

        Paint p = new Paint();

        p.setColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawCircle(mX * scale, mY * scale, 10, p);

        p.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        canvas.drawCircle(mX, mY, 5, p);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to use your solution - see updated question for images. Although circle's doesn't move anymore, it is in the wrong place, plus getScale()'s deprecated.

Comment: Scale in WebView is 0.6698988

Comment: Right, you just arbitrarily decided that it was in the wrong location based on where it was before. There is an initial scale factor that you have to account for if you want it in the same place it was before. If you are questioning the `getScale` deprecation, the alternative is to use a custom `WebViewClient` that overrides `onScaleChanged` and sets some field variable "scale" that is used in your `onDraw`.

Comment: I have custom `WebView`, not sure if it's same with `WebViewClient` though. You were also talking about initial scale, what should I do with it?

Comment: I mean the client set through `WebView.setWebViewClient`. People have been reporting that it is unreliable, so I didn't mess with it.

Comment: Ok. So how can I fix offset with initial scale?

Comment: I've tried your code - didn't fix it. In fact initial scale value is 2.0. Look at updated question for more

Comment: Honestly, like I said, you just decided that the position 1 coordinates were correct by yourself. What exactly makes it correct? The fact that it draws your dot there? The reason that the dot is there is because of some combination of the `setUseWideViewPort` and `setLoadWithOverviewMode`, which zooms the screen out to fit after displaying the screen at the default zoom and after the initial zoom has already been set. If you want to use those settings, then you'll have to figure out how set the intial zoom correctly.

Comment: No, cords are correct, I tested them. I used combination of those two, so image would fit in webview - if he's too large.

Comment: If you know better approach, I'd gladly use it